# Can a windows service speak via the text-to-speech API?

Tags: windows-services, text-to-speech

I have a project that would like to speak (text to speech, TTS) from inside a Windows service.  I understand that no GUI is available inside a Windows service.  Will the speech API work inside a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI is avaivable inside a Windows service. See SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS in WinNT.h and this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And yes, SAPI will work inside a service in the same way as it does in desktop apps.